# What is the simplest way to implement cascade/hierarchial model?

Tags: java, events, model-view-controller, javabeans

There is a class, named [`DefaultListModel<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), which simplifies implementation of list models. But what if list elements are also list models in turn? The parent model should register itself as a listener for child changes and so on. With `DefaultListModel<E>` one should override 7 methods: `add`, `addElement`, `remove`, `removeAllElements`, `removeElement`, `removeElementAt` and `removeRange`.

Is it possible to do simpler?

May be there is some third-party (like commons) library which supports networks of changing beans?

Comment: Why override mentioned methods? Aren't you supposed to implement three methods in the parent (intervalAdded, intervalRemoved, contentsChanged) from ListDataListener, and add that listener to children?

Comment: When to add that listener to children?

Comment: I see what you mean, but you must be aware of the ways the children are added and removed in your model (as I am not). So you could implement the same interface in parent and listen to adds and removals via intervalAdded and intervalRemoved from the same interface, if the changes are not complex to require contentsChanged. If this is not the case, you have to create your own entry points for adding/removal to model, and do the add/remove of listeners.